# Workflow Foundation on a cloud platform

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I'm being asked to come up with a workflow solution for a client who deals with employee-manager requests for time off, etc.  As you might expect these requests can go through a few channels before being approved so I thought workflow foundation would be the way to go.  I know a little about WF but need to study up.

However, I don't know much at all about running workflow services, particularly in a cloud environment (Azure or AWS) and wondered if there were some tutorials out there for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Workflow Manager 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193471%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) that was recently announced.  This is a stand alone server that provides high density workflow execution.  Initially it will be installable on premises as well as on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine; however, in the future they plan to also offer as a service on Windows Azure.

Since it is a stand alone server it could also be deployed to AWS or other virtual machine hosting partners.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Azure Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/), which has approval template built-in.